# Run function after user has stopped typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, timer

I have an input field in which user can input a long value. This value is then used as input value in a complex time consuming function.

My question is: how can I start execution of this function approximately 1 second after the user finished his typing? (I don't want to run it after each key press as it is really slowing the page). So if his next keystroke is in the 1s limit from the last key stroke, than wait additional second.

Do you have any suggestions?

additional note: I also need to pass some parameters into this function

Comment: do you want it to run after he's completely done typing? as in if he focuses out of the textbox? or actually in between keystrokes?

Comment: I know how to run it once the input lost the focus, but this is not what I want to do. The user shouldn't be forced to leave the input once he wants to see the result. So it should be displayed if he is not writing for 1 second and not on focus lost.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here's a rough draft : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/msmJp/

Uses `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`

```js
var timer = null;
    $('#text').keyup(function(){
           clearTimeout(timer); 
           timer = setTimeout(doStuff, 1000)
    });
    
    function doStuff() {
        alert('do stuff');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='text'>
```

Comment: shouldn't the doStuff in setTimeout be in brackets? Also my problem is that I want to pass there some variable values.

Comment: @matej nope, not required. You're passing a function reference. Here's an example that uses params from the outside scope : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/msmJp/1/

Comment: Keyup instead of keydown would make a bit more sense, since we are looking for when the user stopped typing.

Answer (score 4):

This is really late, I know, but I really disliked the lines of code needed to achieve this every time it was needed, so I extracted the logic into a page initiation function that only runs once.

```
(function(){
    var keystoppedTimer = null;
    var keystoppedInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0, l = keystoppedInputs.length; i < l; i++) {
        keystoppedInputs[i].addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
            clearTimeout(keystoppedTimer);
            keystoppedTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                event.target.dispatchEvent( new Event('keystopped') );
            }, 600);
        }, false);
    }
}());
```

Adding this (think of it as a polyfill), allows for much simpler usage. All you need to do to target the user stopping typing is add an event listener to your element targeting 'keystopped'.

```
inputElement.addEventListener('keystopped', function(event){
    console.log('Stopped typing');
}, false);
```

I picked `keystopped` because it matches `keydown`, `keyup`, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I used `input` instead of `keydown`, so it works with copy&paste or dragging text.

Comment: Awesome!! I used document.querySelectorAll('input,textarea'); to also catch those elements

Comment: Absolutely brilliant solution! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [bindWithDelay](http://briangrinstead.com/files/bindWithDelay/) jQuery plugin:

```
element.bindWithDelay(eventType, [ eventData ], handler(eventObject), timeout, throttle)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a solution when it ll show user is typing and user stopped type

```js
function typingAction(){
  $('#typing').text("user is typing....");
clearTimeout();
setTimeout(()=>{
  $('#typing').text(' user stopped typing.....'); //**can call your function here**
  },2000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Chat | ChatApp</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body >
   
<p id="typing"></p>
<input name="message" type="text" placeholder="Message" autofocus autocomplete="off" oninput="typingAction()" />
  


</body>

</html>
```