# How should I approach the timing of this function

Tags: javascript, html

I need to run some code after the user picks the data and year from the input element my HTML page

Here is my JavaScript code

```
var key_form = document.getElementById("key-form");
key_form.addEventListener("input", function () {
setTimeout(function(){let key = key_form.value; alert(key);}, 4000)
})
```

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
        <head>
            <title>Starter Template</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <script src="src/script.js" defer></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <label for="key-form">Pick date for key: </label>
            <input type="date" id="key-form"/>
            <label for="word">Word to encrypt: </label>
            <input type="text" id="word"/>
        </body>
</html>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:

I don’t want it to have a hard 4 seconds limit then run the code which it does. I want it to only run the function when the user is done with giving input.

P.S sorry if question was not clear

Comment: *"Is there a better way to do this?"*: if your code is doing what it is supposed to do (I have no idea), then this question is off topic.

Comment: It does work but, it is a set time of 4 secs then runs the code. I it to run the code after the user finishes giving the data and year

Comment: If i just use event listener once they click on it the code grabs the date of that day and doesn’t let them pick a date.

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what *doesn't* work, preferably with a runnable snippet (use the editor toolbar to insert it). Focus your question on that. You can add the workaround you have for it, but focus on the problem, not the solution.

Comment: Also, be sure to try a few things out. For instance, the `blur` event occurs when the user leaves the control for another one. Perhaps that is a better indicator of when the user is done? Or put a button on the page and check the value when the button is clicked. Typically, one uses a `<form>` element with a `<button type="submit">` to submit the form. That's how HTML5's built-in validation works, for instance. See [MDN's article on forms for more tutorial-type information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms).

Comment: @HereticMonkey The code in that post is not in my programming knowledge base so, it might, I don’t know how to implement it.

Comment: Huh? The answers demonstrate how to implement the code... [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39899635/215552) doesn't use jQuery, if that's what the problem is.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ok sorry. Then I will look at in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So, the question is: How do you know *"when the user is done with giving input"*?**

Maybe your form has a submit button that the user must click?

```js
const key_form = document.getElementById("key-form");
const submit_button = document.getElementById("submit-button");
submit_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let key = key_form.value;
  alert(key);
})
```

```html
<label for="key-form">Pick date for key: </label>
<input type="date" id="key-form"/>
<label for="word">Word to encrypt: </label>
<input type="text" id="word"/>
<button id="submit-button">Encrypt word!</button>
```

Or maybe when the focus is no longer on the date field?

(the  `blur` event fires when a you click outside of the field or press tab when the field has focus)

```js
const key_form = document.getElementById("key-form");
key_form.addEventListener("blur", function () {
  let key = key_form.value;
  alert(key);
})
```

```html
<label for="key-form">Pick date for key: </label>
<input type="date" id="key-form"/>
<label for="word">Word to encrypt: </label>
<input type="text" id="word"/>
```

There are other ways too. Lots of events get fired as form fields get filled out, and they can all trigger any logic you want. So think about how you want the user to interact with this form, then find the right events to support that.

Comment: This is not only a solution, but a good one, because he simply will do his calculations on the date once, instead of doing it every time the user picks